# nginx - location directive regex capture and use

Tags: nginx

I have a very simple requirement and find it very difficult to do in nginx

If you see the location directive, I see a lot of redundancy. How to use regex and match.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /api/a-service/ {
        proxy_pass http://a-service:8080;
    }
    location /api/b-service/ {
        proxy_pass http://b-service:8080;
    }
    location /api/b-service/ {
        proxy_pass http://c-service:8080;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

something like this - but it is not working

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location ~ /api/([a-z\-]+)/ {
        proxy_pass http://$1:8080;
    }


    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not want this. 3 location is not “a lot of” redundancy.

Comment: Nginx’s philosophy is “a little verbose, but simple and efficient”

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I have 20 of them. I just wanted to give an example.